# child of child elements

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a number of rows in my TableLayout and I want to access the button views. Example as follows:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

From the table layout I would like to loop through the buttons.

```
TableLayout layout=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);
layout.getChildCount;
```

The above only returns the number tablerow views.

Comment: You will need some recursion for this

Comment: Why don't you assign ID attribute to each button and access it by tableLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId)  ?

Comment: thanks that would also work nicely because each of the buttons have a unique id...

Comment: would it be possible to use a variable in the place of yourButtonId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this ,it may be help to you

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Table_ID);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
View child = layout.getChildAt(i);

if (child instanceof TableRow) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) child;

    for (int x = 0; x < row.getChildCount(); x++) {
        View view = row.getChildAt(x);//Here you get Your Button View

    }
}
}
```

Comment: @the_big_blackbox always wlc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TableLayout layout=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);
for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++) {
    if (layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TableRow) {
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) layout.getChildAt(i);
        for(int j=0;j<tableRow.getChildCount();j++) {
            if (tableRow.getChildAt(j) instanceof Button) {
                Button button = (Button) tableRow.getChildAt(j);
                //your button is here
            }
        }
    }
}
```